# How to set margins in millimeters?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have `jasperDesign` object with units mm, and I call method `setMargins(myMargin)` to change margins! the problem is with units, I want to setup in millimeters.

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportStream);
jasperDesign.setLeftMargin(newLeftMargin);
jasperDesign.setTopMargin(newTopMargin);
jasperDesign.setColumnWidth(newColumWidth);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then its time to do some calculation

> pixels = (mm * dpi) / 25.4;

The dpi (dot per inch) in jasper report is **72**.

```
public static int getPixels(float mm, int dpi){
    return Math.round((mm*dpi)/25.4f);
}
```